# Dynamic global css variables in svelte

Tags: css, svelte

I'm trying to implement theming in my svelte app. Something simple like:

```
{
  light: { colorPrimary: "skyblue", colorSecondary: "white" },
  dark: { colorPrimary: "white", colorSecondary: "grey" },
}
```

I can easily save this information in the store and also change the theme with a button. The problem is I cant find a good way of passing those variables to css. Its a new app so I'm free to change the style implementation. I have tried:

- Using the svelte native style tag, but there is no way to pass javascript variables to it.
- Using preprocessors like LESS or SCSS, but there is no way to pass javascript variables either.
- Using inline styles directly in the component. This works but I couldnt find any way of highlighting, formatting or linting. And this also create huge components where the functionality is mixed with the style.
- Using inline styles and creating a svelte component for every element of them main component (as styled components work in react), but I have to create a new whole svelte component in a new file for every element, which in unmantainable.

So, is there really no good way of handling something simple as theming in svelte? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason why you define the variables in JS? Because I would not recommend that and just use CSS variables directly.

Comment: I too think you should do this with CSS, but in case you are unaware you can set the value of a CSS variable like this:  `<MyComponent --style:my-var={<JS expression>} />`.

Comment: I'm defining the variables in js so I can change them globally. I know I can change the style of a component inline, but that brings a whole lot of other problems as I mentioned in the last two bullet points

Answer (score 0):

> I'm defining the variables in js so I can change them globally

Just because Svelte component styles are scoped by default, does not mean you cannot have global styles.

You can either use [`:global(selector)`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#style) or `:root` in components or just `import` a separate CSS file in your component `<script>` or a root bootstrapping/layout script.

I usually have something like a `theme.css` and define variables based on attributes (e.g. `html[data-theme=dark]`), possibly combined with [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme).

```css
html {
  --color-primary: skyblue;
  --color-secondary: white;
}
html[data-theme=dark] {
  --color-primary: white;
  --color-secondary: grey;
}
```

Comment: Nice, do you have an example? Or documentation about this? I dont know what 'html[data-theme=dark]' means

Comment: It's just a CSS selector for the document element with a data-attribute (`<html data-theme="dark">`) which you would have to set yourself, e.g. in JS based on a manual theme selection by the user.